# hide html extension + redirect .html version + special case exception

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a hard time understanding htaccess mod_rewrite and while I found several related questions + answers, I unfortunately can't get my very specific situation to work correctly (mod_rewrite is even after hours of searching a book of seven seals to me to be honest)

I have foo.html and bar.html within my root directory. Now, I'd like to have foo.html as the default directory index (solved, easy), but from there I do not get it.

What I want to achieve is:

1. hiding the .html extensions
   user should be able to type `/bar` to get `/bar.html` without seeing the .html (for every .html)
2. 301 redirecting .html version
   user should be able to type `/bar.html` and see `/bar` in the url (avoid duplicate, for every .html)
3. The most tricky part:
   As `foo.html` is default directory index, typing / already shows (transparently) `/foo.html`, but I need typing `/foo.html` to resolve to / as well as typing /foo to resolve to /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting these rules in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine

# 1. hiding the .html extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*?)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.html -f
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html [L]

# 2. 301 redirecting .html version
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.html
RewriteCond %1 !foo$
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]

# 3. typing /foo.html to resolve to / as well as typing /foo to resolve to / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*?/?)foo(\.html)?$
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```

Also, make sure you have Multiviews turned off:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

---

The first rule has 2 conditions, the first groups the URI everything between the first `/` and a possible last `/`. The references it using **%1** in the next condition which sees if the `/path/to/www/document/root/%1.html` is a file that exists. If both are true, it internally rewrites the URI to include a `.html` at the end.

The second rule has 2 conditions, the first matches against the *actual request* as opposed to the URI (which can change as the rules are being applied and rewrites happen). It sees if there's a request that ends with `.html`, and if so, the second condition makes sure that it isn't `foo.html` request (since the last rule handles that). If both are true, then it redirects the browser to the part of the URI without the html, again using **%1** to reference the grouping in the match from the first condition `([^\ ]+)`.

The last rule checks if the request is for a `foo` or `foo.html`. If so, redirect removing that part of the URI.

Comment: I get 500 Internal Server Error. Maybe I should mention that document root is the document root of an addon domain? Does this make any difference? Your code honestly is a book of seven seals on steroids to me.

Comment: Found a typo "Option -Multiviews" needs to read "Options -Multiviews". Also is "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT" maybe another typo? Shouldn't it read "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}"?

Comment: @ThomasKuhn yeah sorry, I typed that up on my phone, let me fix it

Comment: OK, these two typos aside, it works perfect! Thanks a bunch!!! Really! Only a bit unfortunate that I really do not get the code. Will try my best researching to learn out of it. Thanks again!

Comment: @ThomasKuhn You check the green check mark to mark it as accepted. I'll explain a bit in the answer

Comment: Done. I'd also like to credit you somehow. Haven't understood yet how to do.

Comment: @ThomasKuhn you can't upvote until you have 15 reputation, but that's ok.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the more verbose explanation. I *think* I get it (partly at least). Will get back to it again when it isn't 2:40 AM ;-) as I really would like to understand it thoroughly and not just copy&paste. What I can say though, is, that you solved a tough issue I had in a few seconds and I thank you for that! my respect!

Answer (score 0):

I am using the one below and it works except that, in some strange case when working with a WARRANTY script for a client it just won't do the thing.

However; the other scripts that calls external scripts via iFrame in a sub-folder seems to work with the exception of the WARRANTY script. ...

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_END}  =1
RewriteRule ^ - [L,NS]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)\.(php|html?)$        $1   [R=301,NC,NS]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule (.*)$ $1.html   [L,E=END:1,NS]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.htm -f
RewriteRule (.*)$ $1.htm    [L,E=END:1,NS]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule (.*)$ $1.php    [L,E=END:1,NS]
```

I hope this Helps.